# MacOS: Silent auto updates for cocoa command line tool application

Tags: macos, cocoa, auto-update, sparkle

We have a single .pkg file which consists of user app and command line tool app. We are using Sparkle.framework for updates.

While updating, it always asks for admin password.

Is there any way to silently update the command line (root) app in Mac OS?

Comment: Sparkle doesn't trigger admin password request. It's your app. Also having non stop root access would end up all other apps wanting to use your app to get root access to spread malware etc.